# how to configure Gio to open Dockerfile in vscode?

Tags: 22.04

When I run `gio open Dockerfile`, it opens Dockerfile in gedit (/usr/bin/gedit), but I want it to open in Visual Studio Code (/usr/bin/code) instead. How to configure Gio?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully not /the best way/ to solve it, but it's the only way I know how: first run

```
sudo apt-get install php-cli;
```

then make a `/usr/local/bin/giowrapper.php` with

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
// passthru() don't let children inherit stdin/pipes/pty, so use proc_open() instead
// (but even proc_open do not passthru signals, so it's not a perfect solution)
function cmd(string $cmd)
{
    $descriptorspec = array();
    $pipes = array();
    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    $exitCode = proc_close($process);
    exit($exitCode);
}
$cmd = array(
    0 => '/usr/bin/gio',
);
$argstart = 1;
if ($argc === 3 && $argv[1] === 'open') {
    $path = $argv[2];
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) ?: basename($path) ?: $path);
    if (in_array($ext, array(
        'dockerfile',
        // 'py',
        // 'js',
        // 'php',
    ))) {
        $cmd[0] = 'code';
        $argstart = 2;
    }
}
for ($i = $argstart; $i < $argc; ++$i) {
    $cmd[] = escapeshellarg($argv[$i]);
}
//var_dump($cmd);
cmd(implode(' ', $cmd));
```

then run

```
sudo bash -c '
ln -s /usr/local/bin/giowrapper.php /usr/local/bin/gio;
chown root:root /usr/local/bin/giowrapper.php /usr/local/bin/gio;
chmod 0555 /usr/local/bin/giowrapper.php /usr/local/bin/gio;
'
```

and voila, `gio open dockerfile` will now open in vscode!

this approach does have 1 significant drawback however: programs/scripts hardcoded to invoke `/usr/bin/gio` instead of `gio` or `/usr/bin/env gio` will not be affected.